# Is Pig 0.11 compiling slow?

Tags: compilation, apache-pig

Does anyone feel that running scripts on Pig 0.11 slow ? I have run scripts in the same environment with pig 0.11 and Pig 0.8. Pig 0.8 was always faster.

Comments ?

Answer (score 0):

Can it be because of your `LOAD` statements `USING PigStorage()` matches a lot of files? `PigStorage()` in Pig 0.11 checkes schema files on HDFS for the matched file by default. This can make it very slow if you are reading a lot of files.

Use `x = LOAD '...' USING PigStorage('...','-noschema')`. 
Using **-noschema** will avoid looking for schema files and you should be back on speed.

More info [here](http://hadoopified.wordpress.com/2012/04/22/pigstorage-options-schema-and-source-tagging/).